# POWERSHELL: How to run a pipe-tool in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

Goal:

```
$: Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString() }

foo1
foo2

$: Get-ChildItem -File | ..\..\python\modules\foo.py hello-file $_.ToString()

hello, foo1!
hello, foo2!
```

Version I got to run, but not work:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {..\..\python\modules\foo.py hello-file $_.ToString()}
```

---

The BASH equivalent of the above commands:

```
# path vars are set
$: ls | xargs -I {} foo.py hello-file {}

hello, foo1!
hello, foo2!
```

---

Result of the powershell code above:

Instances of CMD windows running python open and close; no output is piped to the terminal.

How does one perform this feat in powershell?  Is it possible to avoid changing the python code?

Comment: What is printed from the running/ non-working version?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm nothing at all; however, if I write, for that same python script, `--help`, I get the correctly formatted content.  Under the hood, the script opens, directly, "/dev/stdout"; perhaps this has the effect of opening a cmd window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the inner workings of you python file is, but I think you'll find that this helps:

```py
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { python ..\..\python\modules\foo.py hello-file $_.ToString()}
```

Adding the word "python" will cause the script to run directly in the current shell.
Therefore any error/results will print where you can see them.

When I ran without explicitly typing "python", a separate python terminal was opened and immediately closed.